# How can we calculate torque required to rotate the wheel (mass unknown)

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Is it possible to calculate torque required to rotate wheel but weight of wheel is unknown?

Comment: A wheel will rotate just as long as you can overcome the friction of the system. So even a very low torque motor can get a well balaced wheel system to rotate, its just going to take a long time to accelerate the system. So no with this info alone you can not answer anything. Not that knowing the wheel geometry helps

Comment: Better yet,  (since you didn't specify), what torque is required to rotate the wheel about a non-axle axis, when the wheel is spinning? (gyroscopic torque)